# Can wi fi direct work permanently?

Tags: android, wifi-direct

wi fi direct switches off after some time on my Android 4.0.3. But I need it to work permanently for my program can send some data periodically on demand from client device. How to overcome this issue?
Morover, ShareIt application works throught wi fi direct without switching it on manually in settings menu. Does anyone know how do they do it?

Comment: Could you please add more details?  Switches off, even when the app is in foreground, or you use wifi direct service from a background service?

Comment: Switches off when the app is in foreground and the screen of the phone is switched off too (blocked).

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. There is an extra option in settings: disable after X min idle. And there is "never" option over there.

Comment: I looked for this settings. But I couldn't find it. I am also facing the same issue. Could you help me with some info?

Comment: What version of android do u have? And tablet or phone?

Comment: it's a smart glass & android version is 4.0.4

Comment: Mine is 4.0.3 lg smartphone. It is possible u have the same option. Enter wifi direct screen and press options (hardware button in my case), then something like "additional options" (i have menu in russian lang). Good luck!