# WiFi Direct disconnects after some time

Tags: android, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I am using an android api 15 device and an api 23 device to send message using WiFi Direct. Initially, everything goes well and I am able to send and receive messages. After some time the app doesn't receive messages and when I go and check the WiFi direct settings, I can see that the connection has been disconnected. This occurs randomly and can't be predicted when the connection will go off.

This is really affecting my testing as suddenly the app doesn't respond to messages sent. I saw this post [Can wi fi direct work permanently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38544601/can-wi-fi-direct-work-permanently) , but I cannot find the mentioned settings in my device.

Is there any other way to tackle this issue? How can I make sure that the connection is not disconnected? Also is there a way, I can set that whenever there is a disconnection, the devices must connect immediately?

Comment: Wi-Fi Direct has a lot of intermittent issues on Android. I compiled a list of Wi-Fi Direct resources a while ago, with some blog posts that talk about some of these issues. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/wi-fi-direct